# Do I need a transit visa for layover in Luanda?

Tags: transit-visas, layovers, uk-citizens, namibia, angola

I am a UK citizen flying from London to Namibia, via Morocco and Angola (what a journey) and have a 9 hour layover in Luanda Airport Angola. Does anyone know if I would need a transit visa for that?

Comment: One ticket or multiple tickets? Your nationality? If the latter you typically will have to pick up your luggage before boarding again, which typically means going through customs. If the former, you typically would be able to stay in the airport. You can check visa requirements at http://cibtvisas.com. And you should really ask your airline what the transfer entails.

Comment: Depends, from South America, TAAG via. Luanda is about half the price of flying over J'burg.

Answer (score 6):

According to [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=1&HEALTH=1&NA=GB&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=NA&EM=MA&TR=AO&VT=00&user=STAR&subuser=STARB2C) you don't need a transit visa:

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>
> Visa required, except for Holders of onward tickets for a max. transit time of 24 hours.

However:

> Angola (AO)
>
> Vaccination against yellow fever required.
>
> Exempt from Yellow Fever vaccination:
>
> - Children under 1 year of age.
> - Passengers transiting Angola who do not leave the aircraft and continue their journey by the same aircraft.