# Transit visa for layover in Angola - U.S. citizen

Tags: visas, transit, us-citizens, angola

I am going to Namibia in 2017. I am U.S citizen. My flight will fly from Amsterdam to Windhoek, it has one stop at Luanda, Angola and the layover time is one and half hour. I assume I do not need Angola transit visa, am I correct? The Angola consulate website just states that visa for transit is required.

Comment: [Previously asked for UK nationals](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50929/do-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-layover-in-luanda)

Answer (score 3):

[According to Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=1&HEALTH=1&page=visa&EM=NL&NA=US&TR=LAD&DE=WDH&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C), the system airlines use to check for travel document requirements, you would not need a transit visa for Angola provided you stay within the transit area at the airport, and meet the other document requirements.

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa): Visa required, except for Holders of onward tickets for a max. transit time of 24 hours.

As always, I would advise you to confirm with the consulate or embassy in case requirements have changed.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not speak Portuguese be prepared for some little frustrations. Make sure you have your passport, International vaccination card with Yellow Fever vaccination and airline ticket ready to present to the immigration officer. The officer will probably speak very little English and will ask you to wait while he summons his supervisor. The supervisor will have some English skills and he will probably take you to the waiting area while they understand what is your situation. Advise that you stay calm, polite and do not loose your cool. Eventually, it will be understood that you are transiting and you will be allowed to enter the flight waiting area. I am a bit concerned with the time since 1 1/2 hours can pass quickly. One final item, assume your bags will be lost or delayed when you get to Windhoek, Namibia. I think that Angola does not get many transit flyers so their processes may be a little rough. Good luck.